# Getting values from zabbix history using zabbix api

Tags: python, json, zabbix

Help me in getting data from zabbix with json in python.
I have take history with exmaple json:

```
data = {
                                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                                "method": "history.get",
                                "params": {
                                        "output":"extend",
                                        "history":"0",
                                        "itemids": i,
                                        "time_from":time_begin,
                                        "time_till":time_end,
                                },
                                "auth": self.authId,
                                "id": 1
                        }
                        request = requests.post(path, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'content-type':'application/json-rpc'})
                        request_res = request.json()['result']
```

The time_begin and time_end, the variable what I take from input, so question.
There is back values only if them exist, and if my zabbix agent didn't work few minutes them was back nothing, and in result hide them. How can I get the zero value or empty value instead of nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Empty Zabbix result is absolutely correct. If Zabbix doesn't know metric value for selected time range, then it can't to declare it as zero.

I recommend you to solve this problem on your app level. But you must be sure that this transformation (NaN=>0) is correct.